# Is it possible to mock an object that is instanciated inside the tested class

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

The method I'm testing looks like :

```
function X($arg)
{
     // Code ...
     $object = new Object;
     // Code ...
}
```

Is there a way to mock that object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a PHPUnit Mock Object in your unit test you can't.

Depending on how you load your classes, you would be able to create a "mock" class which would replace the object.  That would look like this:

Your test file:

```
class Object {
   <mock functionality here>
}

class TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
 <your tests>
}
```

However this will cause problems if you want to actually test `Object` in another test.  In which case you will get a fatal error stating that you cannot redefine the class.  **This is not a best practice.**

Your best bet is to refactor the class so that you use Dependency Injection.  Change the class so that it takes an Object as either a constructor argument or is part of the method signature.

This article may be helpful: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/

Comment: Thanks, I would use Dependency Injection normaly, but I'm testing a code I didn't write, there's no dependency injection and it  has fat, really fat controllers.

Comment: For controllers, I find that you end up with something that most people consider a "integration" test anyway.  This way you get an initial end-to-end test of the API that let's you refactor using DI

Comment: I'm starting to feel that I'm repeating my self, using functional testing with PHPUnit and acceptance testing with Behat, I guess I'll just keep unit testing for models and helpers and acceptance testing for controllers.